# Estimating Sum including the primes dividing N.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, estimation

In a similar question to the one I last asked, there is another result I am struggling to understand. The proof I am studying also uses this line, where p is a prime and N $\in \mathbb{Z}$:

$1+\sum_{p|N}\frac{\log{p}}{p}=O(\log{(\log(3N)}))$

I am sure this result requires the use of Mertens' Theorems in some respect.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum \limits_{p|N} \frac{\ln p}{p} \approx \ln x -1.33258 \leq \ln \theta(x) \leq \ln (\theta(x)+\ln 3) \leq \ln \ln 3N $ which is the maximum value when $N = \prod \limits_{p \leq x} p$

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify where the constant 1.33258 comes from in the method?

Comment: it comes from the approximation of $\sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln p}{p} $,read Pierre Dusart paper about Estimates of functions over primes.